# How to increase page execution time in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, configuration

I want to increase my rail project `page execution time` for `RAILS 3.`

When i load page then in loop more than 1000 data in loop but only load around 136 data only because of complete page execution time.

So, I want to increase page execution time so complete my loop of all data.

LIKE in php set_time_limit(); function to set page time limit same thing i need in rails 3.

So please send me if have a any one.

Comment: The problem most likely is not in Rails but in your server configuration. Please update your question to say more about that.

Comment: I'm not aware of any parameter that prevents rails from exceeding a time limit within the framework itself.  So I agree with davidfurber that it is probably your server configuration.  What server are you using?

Comment: Thanks davidfurber, actually i got ssl issue when curl get data in loop...not execution time issue...

Comment: @harsh4u Did you ever find a resolution to this and, if so, what configuration did you modify to permit longer execution time? Thanks in advance.